# Django get_or_create() is creating multiple rows with the same id

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, postgresql, django-models

I have a get_or_create() in my django app that's creating duplicate rows and assigning them the same id.

```
stock_search, created = SearchRequest.objects.get_or_create(quote=quote, salesperson=user)
```

count() doesn't count these rows more than once but any queries I run on the data returns the duplicated rows.

Any ideas what could be causing this to happen?

Model Definition

```
class SearchRequest(models.Model):
    salesperson             =   models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='sales')
    purchaser               =   models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='purchaser')
    datesent                =   models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, verbose_name=("Date Sent"), blank=True, null=True)
    notes                   =   models.TextField(default='', blank=True, null=True)
    full_search             =   models.BooleanField(verbose_name=("Full Search"), blank=True, default=False)
    quote                   =   models.ForeignKey('Quote.Quote', blank=True, null=True)
    lead_time               =   models.ForeignKey('Logistics.LeadTime', blank=True, null=True)
    call_list               =   models.BooleanField(verbose_name=("Call List"), blank=True, default=False)
    email_list              =   models.BooleanField(verbose_name=("Email List"), blank=True, default=False)
    accepted                =   models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='search_accepted')
    dateaccepted            =   models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, verbose_name=("Date Accepted"), blank=True, null=True)
```

Cheers

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: You need to show us some code. We couldn't imagine from thin air how to solve your problem.

Comment: I've added an example of the code, I've tried it with different fields and I'm getting the same result.

Comment: The line of code is definitely only being executed once.

Comment: There is far, far too little information here to solve your problem or even prove that what you say is happening is true. IDs are generally unique so how you even get many rows with the same ID is a mystery. That means we need to see how your models are set up. If they _are_ unique and you're seeing duplication in a query, we need to see that query/code to determine why there is duplication and if there is a way to solve it. With this little information, there's basically nothing we can do except say, "Sorry that's happening."

Comment: At the very least, post your `Model` definition.

Comment: I've posted the model deffinition, in terms of queries that return the duplicate entries SearchRequest.objects.all() returns them, as does the django admin view

Comment: The model you have added seems to have no relation what so ever to the model you use in your get or create. There no user in it

Comment: Apologies I've now added the actual code line, both user and quote are objects from the related User and Quote tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), you need an unique index for get_or_create to work

> This method is atomic assuming correct usage, correct database
>   configuration, and correct behavior of the underlying database.
>   However, if uniqueness is not enforced at the database level for the
>   kwargs used in a get_or_create call (see unique or unique_together),
>   this method is prone to a race-condition which can result in multiple
>   rows with the same parameters being inserted simultaneously.

So you class needs

```
class SearchRequest(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together('quote','salesperson')
```

which should be placed after the field definitions.

Comment: FYI that's a dead link

Comment: The manual pages keep changing with each release and they don't keep very old pages around